# Your Ruby version is 2.3.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I run a Rails command, it states that my Ruby version is 2.3.1 but my Gemfile specified 2.5.1. However, "ruby -v" returns "ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]", my path has no references to ruby 2.3.1, and running "rvm list" shows a properly green highlighted 2.5.1. Bundler is installed, and when I try to run bundle install inside a created Rails folder, a get another "Your Ruby version is 2.3.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1" message. Please advise.

$PATH:

```
-bash: /home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/alowverus/bin:/home/alowverus/.local/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/alowverus/bin:/home/alowverus/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

Further information in response to answers:
"which rails" returns "/home/alowverus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rails", as expected

Comment: You're need to upgrade ruby up to 2.5.1, and reproduce all steps again.

Answer (score 1):

Create two files in the root one **.ruby-version** mention **ruby-2.3.1** and **.ruby-gemset** mention **@gemset-name** and cd back to the same directory which will create the rvm wrapper for that application then run

```
rvm current
```

which outputs like something

```
ruby-2.3.1@gemset-name
```

then run

```
gem install bundler
bundle
```

may be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I would try (in no particular order):

- `which rails`, is it the correct one?
- `bundle exec rails c` (or whatever your command is)
- `rvm reload`
- To start clean, `rvm implode` and try reinstalling `rvm` and your Ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ruby version is 2.3.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

check ruby version with `ruby -v` [version like 2.3.8] make sure ruby version should be same on ruby versions as well as in your GemFile if you have not the same version then your put command on your bash_profile (terminal) `rbenv global 2.3.8 & rbenv shell 2.3.8` (the version you can specified accordingly ) then delete your Gemfile.lock then install bundle and install bundler . these steps working form me.

```
rbenv global 2.3.8
rbenv shell 2.3.8
delete your Gemfile.lock
install bundle 
install bundler
```